The convergence of an iterative sequence
Let $\circ$ denotes the element-wise product, 1 denotes a vector of all ones, and $\lambda$ is a $d$-dimensional vector with all positive entries.
I want to show the iterative form
$$r_{t+1}=\lambda + r_t \circ \left( 1- \frac{H r_t}{1^Tr_t} \right)$$
converges to the aforementioned unique solution for any positive starting point, where all entries of $H$ are in (0,1) and all entries of
the starting point $r_1$ are positive.
